# The model loaded by Unity AR/VR toolkit is 100 time scaled?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-arvr

I am loading model with Forge AR/VR Toolkit in Unity. I noticed that the model downloaded is about 100 times larger than the original metric scale model. Is that done in purpose? Why?

Answer (score 0):

The AR/VR Toolkit Unity package attempts to scale incoming data to meters (as seen in the [source code](https://github.com/wallabyway/forgeToolkit/blob/master/Forge/CodeBase/ForgeLoaderEngine.cs#L416-L419)), and it's possible that there's some mismatch. Try stepping through the code to see what's going on, or - if you don't mind sharing the original file with us - send it to forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com, and we will take a look.